# Ruby on Rails view iterates through object even when object is nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I am a beginner when it comes to ROR and programming in general. I was working through the basic getting started guide in the documentation and am working on creating a comments view for a blog. I have the following code in my view to render all comments on an article -

```
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter: </strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment: </strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I am having trouble understanding why this code renders the 'Commenter:' and 'Comment:' titles even when there is no comment associated with the specific article?!

I also tried wrapping the above code in -

```
<% if @article.comments.all.empty? == false %>
  <!--Code Above-->
<% end %>
```

just to experiment with it. This will prevent the titles from being rendered if there is no comments however when I add one comment, the title get rendered again in addition to the comment just added. I just need an explanation of this to better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any comments saved in database - it would probably be a blank new comment initialized for the form, that is most likely rendered before the comment list. Try loading existing comments to separate instance variable in controller action:

```
@comments = @post.comments
```

Remember to do it BEFORE initializing a new comment for form. I guess it's initialized in the view with `@article.comments.build`, so simply loading them in controller action should be enough (BTW, it's the right place to do it). Iterate on `@comments` to render list:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
```

Official "Getting Started with Rails" guide puts the form below comment list, possibly to spare beginners such issues. I doesn't mean you're doing it wrong - having form on the top is OK, you just have to make adjustments for that.

Remember that you can always dinstinguish saved and unsaved ActiveRecord objects with [`new_record?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F) and [`persisted?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F) methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. This helped me understand the workings of the MVC better. Basically, it was exactly as you said. Because all comments were being rendered after the new comment initialization through the form and `@article.comments.build` which was causing a nil, unsaved comment with empty Commenter: and Comment: fields to populate. 

Just as an aside, again as per the Getting Started Guide, the comments resource is nested with in my article resource in routes. Is there any advantage/disadvantage of doing this vs creating a seperate resource for comments?

Comment: To be precise - your comment was not `nil`, it was an actual `Comment` object. When you're not sure of what kind of object is in play, it's helpful to check it with `<%= comment %>` or `<%= comment.inspect %>`. As for nested resources - I don't use them often, AFAIK the only benefit is visible in larger apps with many resources, they make routes and url helpers look more organized. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources if you want to use them. Glad to help - I hope my answer is acceptable. Good luck :)

Comment: Your answers were very helpful because they are not just solutions to my specific questions but rather guidelines of how to look at the problem and make sense of it. Thanks again!